How to get last third character out from string without knowing it's length?
I have a string in format of
123*7?8

Where, the symbol ? means it can have any digit in its place. And the symbol * means that any number with a maximum length of 3 characters or nothing can stand in its place.
I'm doing some sort of combination of numbers.
The problem is that I don't know the length of the string because of the '*'. In fact, I need a character with index -3.
This is the code I wrote. But I don't understand how to make the last third character be the number 7.
for (int i = 1000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
    string s = Convert.ToString(i);

    // How can I check that 3d character from the end is '7'?
    if (s[0] == '1' && s[1] == '2' && s[2] == '3' && s.Last() == '8')
    {
        if (i % 23 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}


You do know the length: s[s.Length - 3 - 1] == '7' :)

Thank you! But it should be without - 1, right? Because is with - 1there will be two characters between the 7 and the 8, when there should be one.

@Makar: The length is 1 greater than the last index.  So it's 4 greater than the last index - 3.  Maybe you need the last index - 2?  Either way, you can test to see which index it uses and adjust for your needs.

Probably, you wanted s[^2] == '7'  - which much easier to read.

Having a loop over one billion conversions (ToString()) will be time consuming. I suggest not using string at all and optimizing the loop.

You are actually working with numbers, let's deal with numbers then, not strings, we want
123....7?8
   ^  ^ ^
   |  | digit (0 ... 9)
   |  |
 middle digits (0 ... 999) or none

We can do it as follow:
// -1 stands when we don't have any middle digits
for (int middle = -1; middle < 1000; ++middle) {
    int number = middle < 0
        ? 123
        : 123 * (middle < 10 ? 10 : middle < 100 ? 100 : 1000) + middle;

    for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit) {
        int result = ((number * 10 + 7) * 10 + digit) * 10 + 8; 

        if (result % 23 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(result); 
    }
}

Please, note, that your current solution wants about one billion (999 millions to be exact) conversions (ToString) which can be time consuming. In the code above we loop over just 1001 * 10 = 10010 numbers.
Output (434 lines):
1231788
1232708
...
123991758
123994748
123997738

Fiddle
